# Warning: ldap_mod_replace(): Modify: Server is unwilling to perform

Tags: php

I'm working with Active Directory and i want to change the password of the users. I have all the rights and i get the info of all the users of Active directory, the problem is to change unicodePwd field.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
<?php
function create_ldap_connection() {
$ip = "10.60.0.12";
$ldaps_url = "ldap://$ip";
$port = 636;
$ldap_conn = ldap_connect($ldaps_url, $port)
ldap_set_option(NULL, LDAP_OPT_DEBUG_LEVEL, 7);
ldap_set_option($ldap_conn, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
ldap_set_option($ldap_conn, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);

$password = "administrador";
$binddn = "CN=Administrador,CN=Users,DC=uart,DC=edu,DC=cu";
$result = ldap_bind($ldap_conn, $binddn, $password) or die("
Error: Couldn't bind to server using provided credentials!");
if ($result) {
    return $ldap_conn;
} else {
    die("
Error: Couldn't bind to server with supplied credentials!");
}
}

function get_user_dn($ldap_conn, $user_name) {
$basedn = "DC=uart,DC=edu,DC=cu";
$searchResults = ldap_search($ldap_conn, $basedn, "(samaccountname=$user_name)");
if (!is_resource($searchResults))
die('Error in search results.');
/* Get the first entry from the searched result */
$entry = ldap_first_entry($ldap_conn, $searchResults);
return ldap_get_dn($ldap_conn, $entry);
}

function pwd_encryption($newPassword) {
$newpass = "";
$newPassword = "\"" . $newPassword . "\"";
$len = strlen($newPassword);
for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {
    $newpass .= "{$newPassword{$i}}\000";
}
$userdata["unicodePwd"] = $newpass;
return $userdata;
}

$user_name = "ybolmey"; //Dont remove parentheses brackets
$user_password = "jaciel2014*";
$ldap_conn = create_ldap_connection();
$userDn = get_user_dn($ldap_conn, $user_name);
$userdata = pwd_encryption($user_password);
$result = ldap_mod_replace($ldap_conn, $userDn, $userdata);
if ($result)
echo "Your password has been changed!";
ldap_close($ldap_conn);

?>
```

please help me!! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you got this fixed or not, but you need to use LDAPS in order to change the unicodePwd field.

So this:
$ldaps_url = "ldap://$ip";

Need to be:
$ldaps_url = "ldaps://$ip";